# Solr: Grouping with multiple fields and knowing which field matched the query

Tags: solr

Solr: I have indexed around 5 million rows of data with around 20 fields.

For example, `category`,`subcategory`,`item`,`itemtype`...

I want to search in these 4 fields only and get distinct results.I dont want all the fields in results only 10 fields...there must be about 150-200 distinct results for these 10 fields. But I found out that in Solr we can group with one field only and there is no way to find out which field matched the query.Is there a way to get distinct search results and find out which field matched the query.

Any help would be nice.

Comment: I found out about highlighting to know which field matches the query but that is not useful because that is shown separately along with id of the doc but that would give me around 5 millions different ids. I want to get unique results.

Comment: Is faceting what you're looking for? https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting

Comment: yeah..but I want to group all results in a hierarchy. facet.pivot helps in doing that but it is not possible to know which field matched the query